# Apache HTTP Server Version 2.4 - How to get real IP Address -Centos 7

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-jk

I have a mod_jk httpd server (server ip: dummy1) and it sits  behind a load balancer (server ip : 0.876.123.12 and 0.876.123.13).  Basically when a request comes in it goes to the load balancer then to the httpd server (server ip: dummy2) and then to my application which is deployed on tomcat9 web server (server ip: dummy3).

Note that I have added dummy server IP just in case I need to refer to them and to show that they are on different machines.

My application is currently displaying the ip of the load balancer instead of the client which is using the application.

My code to display the ip is as follows:

```
 String ipAddress1 =httpServletRequest.getRemoteAddr() - this one gets load balancer ip

 String ipAddress2 = httpServletRequest.getHeader("X-Forwarded-For"); - this one is null
```

Based on the online resources I saw that mod_remoteip module for apache should solve my issue and my configuration is as follows:

From the **/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf**

```
# Load config files in the "/etc/httpd/conf.d" directory, if any.
IncludeOptional conf.d/*.conf
```

I am assuming that it will load all file in **/etc/httpd/conf.d** path. Therefore I have created a file **mod_remoteip.conf** in path **/etc/httpd/conf.d** and it is as follows:

```
# Load the mod_remoteip.so module.
LoadModule remoteip_module modules/mod_remoteip.so
# Set the RemoteIPHeader header.
RemoteIPHeader X-Forwarded-For
# Set the back-to-origin IP addresses.
#RemoteIPInternalProxy 0.876.123.12 0.876.123.13
RemoteIPProxiesHeader X-Forwarded-By
```

After creating the file I have  restarted the httpd server but I still get the same behaviour as before, that is:

```
   String ipAddress1 =httpServletRequest.getRemoteAddr() - this one gets load balancer ip
    
     String ipAddress2 = httpServletRequest.getHeader("X-Forwarded-For"); - this one is null
```

Can someone please point me out what I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you don't do anything wrong. It seems that your load balancer simply does not provide information about the original connecting IP, so you can't get an information that is not there. Probably you need to change something on the load balancer, not on your servers.

Comment: You can capture XForwarded IP in the httpd log or you can enable dumio logging which will show more information,